# Почему import "имя модуля" не работает

Tags: webpack, импорт

Хочу большой проект пересобрать в `webpack`.Отделил маленький `ES6` код от файла и поместил в другую.Запустил `webpack` все прекрасно запустилось без ошибок.Но в браузере данная оторванная функцию не работает  показывает **console.error** типо

> `unexpexted string` на первой строке а на первой строке данный код
>   **import "./lang"**

код который подключает другой модуль.С чем связана данная проблема помогите пожалуйста.

вот мой вебпак с простым конфигом **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

const config = {
    entry: "./common.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename:"bundle.js"
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

а это **common.js** повторюсь первая строка ошибка

```
import "./lang";

$('#select-country').selectize();

// --------------------------form open
$(".room-guests-count").click(function(e){
    $(".form-open").toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.form-open').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.form-open').hide();
});
// ---------------------language bar
$('.language').each(function () {
  $(this).find('> .select').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
  $(this).find('.option').on('click', function () {
    $('.language > .select').html($(this).html()).next().slideUp();
  });
});
```

Comment: Да вы сам файл на который ругается покажите лучше.

Comment: @Klimenkomud хорошо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был банально прост я просто включил и common.js и bundle.js потому и ошибку выводил.

Comment: @Air, вообще-то это ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy,  oк...